# US/UK passports and Chinese visa

Tags: usa, uk, dual-nationality, tourist-visas

I have US and UK citizenship and passports. I live in the US. I am traveling to China. Does it matter which passport I use to get visa?

Comment: I might not know how it matters but I would get it on the US passport assuming that the travel plan would be US-China-US. To keep things simple with CBP on re-entry, just in case.

Answer (score 5):

US citizens can now receive 10-year visas to China. Although there has been some talk about this, I don’t believe these are normally issued to British citizens yet, so if you travel to China frequently and are interested in a 10-year visa, applying using your US passport would be best.

Comment: Do you need to specifically ask for it? When I applied for a Chinese visa with my US passport a little while ago, I got a 6 months validity.

Comment: @AleksG It’s at their discretion but my understanding was that it’s given to most people by default, and I know people who have received it. Did you ask for multiple entries and have at least 12 months validity left on your passport?

Comment: Yes to both. That said, this was about 3 years ago, so things may have changed.

Comment: @AleksG the ten-year visa arrangement was concluded in 2014, so I suppose your earlier application was approved before it took effect.  See for example http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/hrsq/.

Comment: @phoog yes, that's what I suspected

Answer (score 0):

As You live in the US and have US citizenship you'd be best off applying for the 10 year visa in your US passport (You need to be both a US Citizen and a US resident to get the 10 year visa - at least that was the case when i got mine in 2016).

With a UK passport most people receive a 2 year visa.